# phpMyAdmin for PHP 7.1 on centos7

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, dependencies

We're trying to install phpMyAdmin on a centos7 box that only has PHP 7.1.  Installing manually is not an option for us.  We're using the remi repo, but getting the following conflicts referencing PHP 5.x packages:

```
# yum list available  --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="remi" | grep -i phpmyadmin
php-phpmyadmin-motranslator.noarch             4.0-1.el7.remi               remi
php-phpmyadmin-shapefile.noarch                2.1-1.el7.remi               remi
php-phpmyadmin-sql-parser.noarch               4.2.4-3.el7.remi             remi
phpMyAdmin.noarch                              4.8.2-1.el7.remi             remi

# yum install phpMyAdmin.noarch --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="remi"
............
Error: Package: php-intl-5.4.45-14.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libicudata.so.50()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-intl-5.4.45-14.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libicuio.so.50()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-recode-5.4.45-14.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: librecode.so.0()(64bit)
Error: php71u-json conflicts with php-common-5.4.45-14.el7.remi.x86_64
Error: php71u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.45-14.el7.remi.x86_64
Error: Package: php-intl-5.4.45-14.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.50()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-intl-5.4.45-14.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.50()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-common-5.4.45-14.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libzip.so.2()(64bit)
```

Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: have you tried #yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php54 install phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but packages in "remi" repository won't work with other 3rd party repostiory (like IUS)

You have to enable "remi", "remi-safe" and "remi-php71" if you want phpMyAdmin with latest PHP 7.1

Comment: Thank you!  I will try this out and report back

Comment: Update: We're still getting:

Error: php72u-common conflicts with php-common-7.1.21-1.el7.remi.x86_64

Comment: Disable IUS which create tons of conflicts

Comment: Hi @RemiCollet, How to "Disable IUS"